# Sum of memory usage of all pods is not equal to node's memory usage in Kubernetes - Datadog

Tags: kubernetes, memory, memory-management, datadog

I have around 18 pods running in my one of the Kubernetes node. I am using Datadog to monitor the cluster.

Sum of memory usage of all pods is not equal (or not even near) to the memory usage of the host.

I use "kubernetes.memory.usage" by pod_name to get the memory usage of each pod.
I use "system.mem.used" by host to get the memory usage of the node.

In the metrics explorer I have 18 queries for "kubernetes.memory.usage" and 1 query for "system.mem.used". And I have a formula to sum the values of 18 queries. (a+b+c+d)

So, I get two lines in the graph.

1. For sum of memory usage of all pods
2. For memory usage of the node where pods running

Sum of memory usage of all pods is not equal (or not even near) to the memory usage of the host.

Upper line is the node memory usage. Lower line is the sum of memory usage of all the pods.

[image]

What is that am missing?

Comment: Have you seen this question?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/60813395/7368018

Comment: @Aleem thanks, just looked into it. But that question talks about the pod's memory utilization between "ps" and "metrics-server". And it suggests to go with the "metrics-server" value since "ps" could be misleading. In my question, I am already looking at the value given by Datadog. And seeing difference in total pod memory and the node memory utilization.